# Display Count or Total for each user in ASP.Net MVC table using View Model (vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, model

I am pulling all users from a SQL Server DataTable and displaying that list in a table (See Code)

Controller Code:

```
Function Display Users() As ActionResult

Using db as new xDataContext

Dim model As New dataViewModel With { _
                                      .AllUsers = db.GetAllUsers() _
                                      }

            Return View(model)

        End Using
```

Model Code:

```
Public Function GetAllUsers() As List(Of User)
    Dim allusers = From user In Me.Users Select user Order By user.LastActivityDate Descending
    Return allusers.ToList()
End Function
```

HTML Code:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>User/<>
            <th>Total Points</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

        <% For Each item in Model.AllUsers%>

            <tr>
                <td><%: item.UserId%></td>
                <td>NEED HELP HERE I want to show points from a separate table summed life to date </td>
            </tr>
        <% Next%>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

UserId's are stored in a user datatable and I can get those records easily.  Points are stored in a separate table by date. What I am trying to get is the total number of points by summing all of the points for each user and displaying it in the table. This may be easily solved and I am just being dense...

I have searched for ways to accomplish this to no avail.  Any help in doing this is appreciated.

Thank you for the quick reply.  I am sorry I did not give enough info.  I have two tables: Users and Activities - Activities contains points per activity that I want to sum life to date by user in the table.  They are separate and I want to combine them in the View Table.
Example:
User              Points
Ted                127
Sam                211

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a vb.net person but you should get an idea as how to do this from following query:

```
var allUsers = from T1 in context.Users
        join T2 in context.Points on T1.ID equals T2.ID
        group T3 by new { T1.ID} into g
        select new { 
            Column1 = T1.Column1, 
            Column2 = T2.Column2, 
            Amount = g.Sum(t3 => t3.Column1) 
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

For model.
Create one wrapper class which able to hold data from two table like UserWrapper where you put userdata and other table data.you can also add one more member variable in your current class if you dont want to create another wrapper class.

For controller fire join query to select from two table

```
SELECT *
FROM user INNER JOIN othertable
ON user.userId= othertable.userId;
```

your both table must have some comman thing on which you can fire the query here which is userId.

then you can put on view as you are doing...